# Connect openVpn

Tags: openvpn, ip, router

I'm trying to connect via openVpn. I have ubuntu 20.04.
My client.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn.stend1.vs.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert n.john.crt
key n.john.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
comp-lzo
verb 3

#mtu 1460
```

I have error

```
Wed Apr 13 19:15:28 2022 /sbin/ip route add 10.22.208.1/32 via 10.22.208.102
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Wed Apr 13 19:15:28 2022 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Wed Apr 13 19:15:28 2022 /sbin/ip route add 10.22.208.1/32 via 10.22.208.102
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Wed Apr 13 19:15:28 2022 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Hello. First problem I see is no Ubuntu version in the question. Are you using Ubuntu and if so what version?

Comment: The "`FILE EXISTS`" error means, in this case, that there are Existing routes (probably from previous tries) that the new route would overlap. See `ip route`, read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: @David thank you, i use ubuntu 20.04